# Instantiating an Angular interceptor

Tags: angular

I have an interceptor for which I try to output a logger in its constructor so as to make sure the interceptor is instantiated.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

import { ErrorCustomHandler } from './error-custom-handler';

// Because the best Error is the one that never happens, improve the error handling
// using an HttpInterceptor to intercept all the server calls and retry them n times
// before throwing an error
const NB_RETRIES = 5;

@Injectable()
export class ErrorRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private errorCustomHandler: ErrorCustomHandler
    ) {
        console.log('In the constructor of error request interceptor');
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).retry(NB_RETRIES).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { }, (error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                this.errorCustomHandler.handleError(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The interceptor is registered as:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ErrorCustomHandler } from './error-custom-handler';
import { ErrorService } from './error.service';
import { ErrorRoutingModule } from './error-routing.module';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error-component/error.component';
import { ErrorRequestInterceptor } from './error-request-interceptor';

// See https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ErrorComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        ErrorRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        ErrorService,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: ErrorCustomHandler
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorRequestInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        }
    ]
})
export class ErrorModule { }
```

I can see that the interceptor source file is being executed.

But the constructor logger is never displayed in the browser console.

I'm using Angular 6

The complete source code is available on [github](https://github.com/stephaneeybert/ng-hero)

EDIT: I moved the provider into a `forRoot` method and import that module in the app module with a `ErrorModule.forRoot()` statement:

```
export class ErrorModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: ErrorModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                    useClass: ErrorRequestInterceptor,
                    multi: true,
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

But it didn't change anything, the interceptor constructor is still not firing.

UPDATE: No need for the `forRoot()` method. I was missing the ErrorCustomHandler injected service in the providers of the error module.

```
ErrorCustomHandler,
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorRequestInterceptor,
    multi: true,
}
```

LATE UPDATE (25/10/2018): The interceptor has been firing up fine for a long time now, and since I forgot to provide a solution in due time, I shall add the working modified source code here.

The change is within the `error.module.ts` file:

```
providers: [
    ErrorService,
    {
        provide: ErrorHandler,
        useClass: ErrorCustomHandler
    },
    ErrorCustomHandler,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ErrorRequestInterceptor,
        multi: true,
    }
]
```

The `ErrorCustomHandler` class is now registered as a provider.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I just added a late update in the question for you to see.

Comment: I just added a late update in the question for you to see.